# MySQL DELIMITER not working

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, delimiter

I've tried a tutorial from [this site](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/29/adjacency-list-vs-nested-sets-mysql/), where a sample table gets inserted along with some testing data in a stored procedure. But unfortunately an error message is thrown, saying there's something wrong with the `DELIMITER`. The whole script is:

```
CREATE TABLE filler (
    id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT
) ENGINE=Memory;

CREATE TABLE t_hierarchy (
    id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    parent INT NOT NULL,
    lft INT NOT NULL,
    rgt INT NOT NULL,
    sets LineString NOT NULL,
    data VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    stuffing VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM;

DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE prc_filler(cnt INT)
BEGIN
    DECLARE _cnt INT;
    SET _cnt = 1;
    WHILE _cnt <= cnt DO
            INSERT
            INTO    filler
            SELECT  _cnt;
            SET _cnt = _cnt + 1;
    END WHILE;
END;

CREATE PROCEDURE prc_hierarchy(width INT)
main:BEGIN
    DECLARE last INT;
    DECLARE level INT;
    SET last = 0;
    SET level = 0;
    WHILE width >= 1 DO
            INSERT
            INTO    t_hierarchy
            SELECT  COALESCE(h.id, 0) * 5 + f.id,
                    COALESCE(h.id, 0),
                    COALESCE(h.lft, 0) + 1 + (f.id - 1) * width,
                    COALESCE(h.lft, 0) + f.id * width,
                    LineString(
                    Point(-1, COALESCE(h.lft, 0) + 1 + (f.id - 1) * width),
                    Point(1, COALESCE(h.lft, 0) + f.id * width)
                    ),
                    CONCAT('Value ', COALESCE(h.id, 0) * 5 + f.id),
                    RPAD('', 100, '*')
            FROM    filler f
            LEFT JOIN
                    t_hierarchy h
            ON      h.id >= last;
            SET width = width / 5;
            SET last = last + POWER(5, level);
            SET level = level + 1;
    END WHILE;
END
$$

DELIMITER ;

START TRANSACTION;
CALL prc_filler(5);
CALL prc_hierarchy(585937);
COMMIT;

CREATE INDEX ix_hierarchy_parent ON t_hierarchy (parent);
CREATE INDEX ix_hierarchy_lft ON t_hierarchy (lft);
CREATE INDEX ix_hierarchy_rgt ON t_hierarchy (rgt);
CREATE SPATIAL INDEX sx_hierarchy_sets ON t_hierarchy (sets);
```

Executing this on a MySQL 5.0.51a-24+lenny2 server gives me the following error message:

> [Err] 1310 - End-label $$ without match

Does anyone know why this occurs and how to fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$ should be after every created procedure.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE prc_filler(cnt INT)
BEGIN
    DECLARE _cnt INT;
    SET _cnt = 1;
    WHILE _cnt <= cnt DO
            INSERT
            INTO    filler
            SELECT  _cnt;
            SET _cnt = _cnt + 1;
    END WHILE;
END$$ -- here's your problem
```

That's why it is called delimiter - it separates SQL commands. You have ';' inside procedures and '$$' outside of them.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't see this. I changed it according to your post (I had to replace a `END;` with `END$$` some lines before, too) and it works now :-)

Answer (score 0):

I have seen some MySQL clients that don't support the DELIMITER keyword and throw an error... I believe it is your case... You should try to use a different client, maybe the CLI tool bundled with MySQL (if you can...)?

Comment: I'm using Navicat which supports it, but thanks for the hint nevertheless.